# ng test hangs after successful tests in Github Actions

Tags: angular, continuous-integration, jasmine, github-actions, karma-jasmine

I added a step in my Github Actions workflow to run my Angular tests using the command `ng test`. The tests run and pass successfully but it never moves onto the next step in my workflow.

What have I tried:

- Adding the argument watch=false in the step so that "ng test" isn't watching for file changes.
- Setting `singleRun` to true in karma.conf.js

Nothing's worked so far and I'm not seeing any other resources that can help me solve this issue.

Here is a snippet of the step in my build-push.yml file:

```
- name: Run tests
  run: npm test -- --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless
```

Here is a snippet of my karma.conf.js file:

```
reporters          : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
port               : 9876,
colors             : true,
logLevel           : config.LOG_INFO,
autoWatch          : true,
browsers           : ['Chrome'],
singleRun          : false,
restartOnFileChange: true,
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of the workflow running in Github Actions. I expected "Post Set up Node" to run but it just hangs on the tests even after all the tests have passed.]

The above image is a screenshot of the workflow running in Github Actions. I expected "Post Set up Node" to run but it just hangs on the tests

Any help is greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on this for quite some time now. Thank you all!

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution for this? I've been stuck with the same problem for a while :)

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, `ng test` out-of-box runs, then watches to re-run tests on files you change. Angular has some flags to make testing using [continuous integration](https://angular.io/guide/testing#testing-in-continuous-integration) easier.

This worked for me:

**package.json**:

`"test-ci": "ng test --no-watch --no-progress --browsers ChromeHeadless",`

- I made a separate command so I could run tests locally *and* in CI without needing to change each time
- you need ChromeHeadless, or you get failures trying to start the GUI version of Chrome on the runner (and you don't need that, anyways)

**karma.conf.js**:

don't need this, but if you want other tweaks, keep that in

**test.yml**:

```
...
- name: Test
  run: |
    npm install
    npm run test-ci
```

[proof of functional test run](https://github.com/meldaravaniel/mybr/actions/runs/5481705507/jobs/9986300168) :)